# Spring Batch: Unsupported Database Type for Hive

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hive, spring-batch, cloudera

I'm trying to create a DataSource for my step, that uses a Cloudera Hive Server 2 driver to connect to a table in Hadoop. Though I've had success with this driver in other use cases, trying to use it in Spring Batch spits out this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found
>   for product name: [Apache Hive]

I've created a datasource in application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
      url: <URL>
      username:
      password:
      driver-class-name: com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver
```

I noticed that this database type is not supported in the list found in `DatabaseType.java`. What is frustrating is I can't use the Apache Hive Driver for my connection due to other issues, so I need to find a way of telling Spring that this is a valid connection pool, or even spoof it into thinking its a mysql connection.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into below code, this will give you idea how to implement "Hive-Spring" connection.

**Using the Hive JDBC Client**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- basic Hive driver bean -->
    <bean id="hive-driver" class="org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"/>

    <!-- wrapping a basic datasource around the driver -->
    <!-- notice the 'c:' namespace (available in Spring 3.1+) for inlining constructor arguments, 
         in this case the url (default is 'jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default') -->
    <bean id="hive-ds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource"
       c:driver-ref="hive-driver" c:url="${hive.url}"/>

    <!-- standard JdbcTemplate declaration -->
    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" c:data-source-ref="hive-ds"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="hive.properties"/>
</beans>
```

**Running a Hive script or query**

```
<hdp:hive-runner id="hiveRunner" run-at-startup="true">
   <hdp:script>
     DROP TABLE IF EXITS testHiveBatchTable; 
     CREATE TABLE testHiveBatchTable (key int, value string);
   </hdp:script>
   <hdp:script location="hive-scripts/script.q"/>
</hdp:hive-runner>
```

[For more details you can refer to this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/hive.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, though this XML based response has no meaning to me unfortunately, is there anyway you could kindly give me an idea of what this will look like in Java?

Comment: Did you tried to use "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" class to connect ot Hive.